# Why is this double type variable default to int when passed as a function parameter?

Tags: c, variable-declaration, function-parameter

I am learning C and was trying to help debug a friends code. 
He was defining his function parameters in the global scope and then passing them into the function def like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double x;


double myfunc(x){
    return x;    
}

void main(){

}
```

I get this is wrong, but not why the following error comes up:

```
main.c:14:8: warning: type of ‘x’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

Can someone help me understand how the computer is interpreting this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *He was defining his function parameters in the global scope*

No, he does not.

The global `x` is unrelated to the function's parameter `x`.

The former is a global `double`, the latter is local to the function and, as the compiler is warning, "*defaults to `int`*".

> *I get this is wrong*

It is not wrong, but not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable

```
double x;
```

has no relation to the parameter `x` of `func`.

Since the type of `x` isn't provided, compiler defaults to `int` type (pre-C99). But this assumption isn't valid since [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

So either specify the type for `x` (such as: `double func(double x) { ...}`) or simply don't pass any argument to it at all if you want to use the global `x`.

As a general rule, avoid globals. Or at least make it `static` so that it's not visible outside the translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is using an older, K&R-style of function definition, where parameter types are specified separately from the parameter list.  If done correctly, it would look like this:

```
double myfunc(x)
  double x;
{
  return x;
}
```

However, it's better to use prototype syntax, where the parameter type is specified with the parameter name:

```
double myfunc( double x )
{
  return x;
}
```

Note that this parameter `x` has nothing to do with the global variable `x` - it is an entirely separate object.

Under older versions of C, if a function had no return type, or if a parameter wasn't declared with a type, the compiler assumed it had type `int`.  Implicit `int` typing was done away with in the 1999 standard IINM, and shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
double myfunc(x){
    return x;    
}
```

you are declaring a function in the legacy style of the first edition of Kernighan & Ritchies book "The C Programming Language".

That style, still alive, allows you to declare a function just naming its parameters (which are **always local to the function**, so the global `x` is a different variable than the parameter `x` to the function)  and, as you don't specify its type, it defaults to `int`.  So you are actually declaring (in ANSI-C) the following function:

```
double myfunc(int x){
    return x;    
}
```

and, as you see, it takes an integer parameter.

Parameters to a function are **ALWAYS** local to the function, you cannot make them global variables.

## Note:

If you want to define the function in old style C, the proper definition would be:

```
double myfunc(x)
    double x;
{
    return x;    
}
```

in ANSI-C is:

```
double myfunc(double x)
{
    return x;    
}
```

I tried to compile the next program in my computer:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double myFunc(x)
{
        return x;
}

int main()
{
        printf("%g\n", myFunc(M_PI));
}
```

with the following **WARNING**:

```
$ make pru
cc -O2 -pipe  pru33336.c  -o pru33336
pru33336.c:11:24: warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 3.141592653589793 to 3 [-Wliteral-conversion]
        printf("%g\n", myFunc(M_PI));
                       ~~~~~~ ^~~~
/usr/include/math.h:149:15: note: expanded from macro 'M_PI'
#define M_PI            3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
$ _
```

So you can see that an automatic conversion is being made to convert the double passed to the function into an `int`, to comply with the parameter type.  If you run the program, you'll get just

```
$ pru
3
$ _
```